# Hibernate Anntotaion @Converter need to be configure before Spring Anntotation @propertySource

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using @converter (Hibernate )to convert pojo in encrypted format which is from hibernate but key are placed in property file which would not be resolve by @propertySource (Spring annotation)

is there any way to manage bean creation seq in above case.

Comment: Can you please add relevant part of source code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code snippet for Converter, I had created another bean from encryption/decryption, but you can create config bean for properties and read properties from there.

```
@Component
@Converter
@Configurable
public class HashMapConverter implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, Object>, String> {

    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    /*
     * Define your application properties bean here and read the properties from
     * there
     */
    private static ConfigEncryptionKeyConverter configEncryptionKeyConverter;

    @Autowired
    public void initEncryptionKeyConverter(ConfigEncryptionKeyConverter configEncryptionKeyConverter) {
        // Set your beans here.
        HashMapConverter.configEncryptionKeyConverter = configEncryptionKeyConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Map<String, Object> attribute) {
        try {
            return configEncryptionKeyConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(OBJECT_MAPPER.writeValueAsString(attribute));
        } catch (final JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new ApplicationErrorException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {

        Map<String, Object> attribute = null;
        if (dbData != null) {
            try {
                attribute = OBJECT_MAPPER.readValue(configEncryptionKeyConverter.convertToEntityAttribute(dbData),
                        Map.class);
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                throw new ApplicationErrorException(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
        return attribute;

    }

}
```

Hope this will help.